# Unhandled exception happens in my animation when using  Pushpins

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having the problems overall with animations - I just don't get it:)

Here what I want to achieve is to show my own location in map using the some nice image and I have been trying to animate it. Here in this example just turning it over. Point is not what kind of animation but animation and getting it working overall - now I'm getting unhandled exception without any good information.

```
<my:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinsImage}">
  <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <my:Pushpin x:Name="PushpinImage1"
                  Style="{StaticResource PushpinStyle3}"
                  Location="{Binding PushpinLocation}"
                  MouseLeftButtonUp="Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <Image x:Name="PointMe" Source="{Binding PushpinImage}">
          <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="180" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="PointMe" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>                                                    
            </EventTrigger>
          </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>    
      </my:Pushpin>
    </DataTemplate>
  </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</my:MapItemsControl>
```

and here is the pushpintstyle3 style from appl.xaml:

So what is wrong with my code. Overall I'm having great problems with animation.

Comment: Please, post the exception details (type, stack trace, message, whatever) here.

Comment: Jeah, very good point, I didn't even look at that in the FIrst Phase:

Comment: System.EventArgs {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
_exception {"Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY) on specified object."} 
System.Exception {MS.Internal.WrappedException} _handled false bool
ExceptionObject {"Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY) on specified object."} 
System.Exception {MS.Internal.WrappedException} Handled false bool

Answer (score 2):

As MSDN says, `Projection` property value is null by default. Therefore, you should add some default projection:

```
<Image x:Name="PointMe" Source="{Binding PushpinImage}">
  <Image.Projection>
    <PlaneProjection />
  </Image.Projection>
...
</Image>
```